# Is there any way to edit a published site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, mc

I have an website my code is c# mvc razor cshtml and i lost the main project code and i have just the published site surce i wanna know can i change and edit the site and connect to database and execude the new codes and function ?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to say NO my dear friend , if the change is on controller or model side.
You can get the the Dll's of the project from the source folder(iis,ado artifact).

Answer (score 0):

You can have "a zero downtime" strategy for that, but it doesn't mean that will be easy to execute. Let's say your application is behind a load balancer with 2 webservers

1. Redirect the traffic to webserver #1
2. Deploy the application to webserver #2 pointing to database #2(backup of database #1 +  new changes)
3. Redirect the traffic to webserver #2 (users at this point will get the new functionality, but you can have some records persisted on the database #1 that are not part of the database backup you did on step #1 at the moment of the migration
4. Migrate data from database #1 to database #2
5. Deploy the code to webserver #1
6. Re-establish again the load balancer

If you are deploying to IIS please check this website it has a full guide of how to do it
[Zero downtime](https://kevinareed.com/2015/11/07/how-to-deploy-anything-in-iis-with-zero-downtime-on-a-single-server/)